# how to update/change the interval of task in celery beat django during run tim?

Tags: django, django-celery-beat

I want to know how to change the interval of a task in django celery beat during run time?
For instance, I have the code below:

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
  'every_5_seconds': {
        'task': 'my_app.tasks.cpu',
        'schedule': 5,
        }
}
```

Now, I start celery beat using redis as broker:
Celery -A my_project worker -l info
Celery -A my_project beat -l info

The question is, how can I change/update the schedule to a new one (20 seconds instead of 5) while it's rinning and vise versa.

Thanks